# Register a function that appends a predicate to all emited queries

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Using Python and SQLALchemy, I've written this code that tries to append a "where company_id=x" for each database interaction:

```
 @event.listens_for(engine, 'before_execute', retval=True)
 def append_where_clause(conn, clause, multiparams, params):
     if isinstance(clause, sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Insert):
       
        values = clause.values
        values["company_id"] = int(os.environ['COMPANY_ID'])
        clause = clause.values(**values)

     elif isinstance(clause, (Select, Update, Delete)):
        clause = clause.where(text(f"company_id ={int(os.environ['COMPANY_ID'])}"))

return conn, clause, multiparams, params
```

If I inspect the echoed SQL ( echo=True at engine creation), I dont see the predicate appended, but I thought may be the function is called after the echo. If I `print(clause)` inside the method I can see the predicate added but the data is still not filtered, I think somehow the updated clause does not reach the database. Any idea?

Comment: It works for me, though I get a deprecation warning for the signature.

Comment: It does not work for me. I'm using SQLAlchemy==1.4.5. Even so, I'm not sure this approach should solve my problem. Could you help me if I describe the problem to you?

Comment: Yes, in case this is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  Also, please clarify whether you need the behaviour for core, ORM, or both.

Comment: I developed a business management app. It works for company A. The same people have different businesses, say, A, B, C,... They want to run the same app for all companies and also, automate some processes, for example, create a sale in A and automatically create the related purchase in B. I could create different databases or add a new field with a foreign key to a table that holds company necessary data for rendereing documents, etc. And listen to the engine in order to append to any database interaction a predicate "where company_id = x". The x is stored as a global variable for the app.

Comment: I think I will to the multiple database approach. Much easier.

Comment: [This](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/_modules/examples/extending_query/filter_public.html) might be of some interest.